# get_where codeigniter return value of single column in table

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is what i'm trying to do `select kodemk from tik.matakuliah where namamk = $data['namamk']`. I'm trying to get the value of a single column called `kodemk` from table named `tik.matakuliah` witch certain conditioning with codeigniter 3

So far, this is my code

`'kode_mk' = $this->db->get_where('tik.matakuliah',array('namamk'=>$data['mk']))->result()`

What should i do to achieve what i want to do? because my code will retrieve `*` or all of it while i only want certain column value of the table which is `kodemk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select query` instead of plain `get query`, like so -

```
$kodemk = $this->db->select('kodemk')->from('tik.matakuliah')->where(array('namamk'=>$data['namamk'])->get()->result();
// returns select kodemk from tik.matakuliah where namamk = $data['namamk']
```

See if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
     $this->db->select('kodemk');
     $this->db->where('namamk', $data['namamk']);
     $kodemk = $this->db->get('kodemk')->result();
     return $kodemk;
```